# How the author came up with the solution to the problem?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I have been reading this book on Machine learning. I have no problem in understanding the Union, intersection and complementation and other terms. But while I was following the author in the solution of the problem, I could not figure out, how he know whether I have to pick Union, Intersection and symmetric differences.  I shall be very grateful to you all if you put some light on this problem. Regards[image]

Snapshot is attached

Answer (score 2):

Union is either/or. So there are 28 cards in the deck which are either black or an ace. The card under consideration to be counted may be either (1) black and not an ace or (2) black and an ace or (3) red and and ace.

Intersection is both. There are two black aces in the deck. (The card under consideration to be counted must both be black and aces).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.... actually I had to ask that how the author could decide on what kind of  different combinations of Union and intersections I have to use to come out with a solution of the above-mentioned problem.

Comment: It is an EXAMPLE problem. The solution for each of the cases (a-g) is described in the image.

Comment: The first sentence sets up that card problems are two be solved. The second sentence gives problems to be solved (a-g). The rest describes the solutions.

Comment: Oh... I got it now... thank u max... individually I have solved them all...